ERROR: Insert or update on table "idn_oauth2_token_binding" violates foreign key constraint
I am using wso2 IS version 6.0 with postgres database and I often see the below error in the logs of wso2 though the functionality works fine.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "idn_oauth2_token_binding" violates foreign key constraint "idn_oauth2_token_binding_token_id_fkey"

How do I fix this and what is causing the error?
